# PC register changes supplied value

Tags: ios, buffer-overflow, armv7

I'm new to buffer overflows and although I believe I get the process, I feel that something is wrong here. I am studying from a book about exploitation and in the example, there is a simple buffer overflow on a 16 bytes string. This is the code of the binary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void vuln(){
    char buff[16];
    scanf("%s",buff);
    printf("You entered: %s",buff);
}

void secret(){
    printf("My secret is 131313");
}

int main() {
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can guess, the goal is to call the secret function. I compile it on my Mac using Clang with the following arguments `-arch armv7` `-fno-stack-protector` `-fno-pie`, so no protection and ARMv7 architecture. It runs normally on the iPhone and when it asks for user input I enter 32 bytes, in groups of four like this `AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHH`. When the application crashes I check on iOS logs and I can see that the crashing happens where the `F`s start from.

What I expected to see, is that the `pc` register will have value `0x46464646` for F, but actually it returns `0x46464644`.

These are the values of the registers at the time of crash.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                             0x46464644 0 + 1179010628

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x0000002d    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x3ba30f80      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x0000bf71      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x45454545
    r8: 0x00201854    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00012068    sp: 0x00201834      lr: 0x0000bf53      pc: 0x46464644
  cpsr: 0x40000010
```

Also, I tried with just 40 `A`s and it returned `0x41414140`. Why it does not return the input entered as expected?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue as me, I found out that r15 or pc should always be divided by 4 in ARM. From the official [ARM Documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/ch11s03s04.html):

`Note that r15 cannot be used with writeback, and that offset must be divisible by 4`